# Defer parsing javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, parsing

I try to let my website load faster. I ran a speedtest and came across "defer parsing javascript".
I used different sites to run a speedtest.
Those suggested to put the external js in 1 file.
I found a script on this site: [defer parsing js script](http://geniushowto.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-do-defer-loading-of-javascript.html) and used that.
This before the last body:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "defer.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

And this in the defer.js:

```js
(function() {
      function getScript(url,success){
        var script=document.createElement('script');
        script.src=url;
        var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            done=false;
        script.onload=script.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
            done=true;
            if(success && getScript.call(success) == '[object Function]') { success(); }
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);
          }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
      }
 getScript('
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',function(){
getScript('highslide/highslide-full.js');
getScript('javascripts/bootstrap-v3.2.0.min.js');
getScript('http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js');
getScript('js/jquery.flexslider-min.js');
getScript('http://chs02.cookie-script.com/s/3e2959acb953e61e326f4716f65b6748.js');
getScript('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
getScript('js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js');
getScript('javascripts/dropdown-custom.js');
getScript('js/touchTouch.jquery.js');
getScript('js/jquery.cookie.js');
        });
    })();
```

But when I test that, the dropdown menu, the slider and my highslide images don't work properly. What can I change so that it will work?
This is the testpage: [testpage](http://www.tina-turner.nl/test.php)

Johanna

Comment: are you loading scripts before loading dom?

Comment: check your browser console for errors, there will be errors !

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Sorry I am not very good in this.

Comment: that's actually going to be a lot slower than hard-coding external script tags

Comment: How do you manage the dependencies? Why don't you use the `async`/`defer` attribute of the `script` tag instead?

Comment: I didn't know about that. I will try and use the defer attribute to see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Also if this is for SEO, don't pay attention to the stupid warnings of the Google speedtest. Those parameters do no have any strong effect on SEO. Google web search simply doesn't care much about website speed and quality. Google search now is a marketing tool and likes the marketers more than developers, it ranks the yellow-page websites higher than user-friendly/fast websites.

Comment: Ok I changed the script to defer and that works! The only thing not working is the highslide. It won't work either with defer or with async.
Isn't it possible to defer that one too?

Comment: This is why I had written: "How do you manage the dependencies?".

Comment: Vohuman, what does that mean?

Comment: I mean since the scripts depend on other scripts in order to work, you can't load them in parallel. You can concatenate the scripts and serve just 1 script file in the document. I usually use http://gulpjs.com/ for this, but you can also do it manually and then "uglify"/minify the created js file. There are also several online services for this: http://jscompress.com/

Comment: Ok thanks. But I found out, that only the "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" didn't work with defer. I used the async attribute and now all is working.
Thanks you all for your input! :D